# nvm vs nave vs n | packages processing comparsion

Tags: node.js, versioning, nvm

Node.js is sometimes confusing when it comes to version management...

I am trying to arrange various projects as i am doing with ruby projects. For example:

With ruby i can create file such as `.rvmrc` and fill with something like `rvm --create use 1.9.3@my-app`

This thing creates and uses all gems specifically to configured gemset. Which allows to have various options for any kind of project, and switch easily among them. So ruby does this in one place.

I want to achieve this for node.js projects.

Node works differently. I want to know the details about that, and especially of each node version management tool.

## The point is to know which version management tool for which goal...

### And why there are so many.

More accurately: i want `npm install <package-name>` to chosen node version. And after switching to other versions, this installed package to be missing, or have different version installed before (or certain one). Just like `gemset` is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for clarification too:

- Both allow switching & installing between node versions.
- nvm will symlink the different versions to /usr/local/bin/node, and n will move your node installs to the path (/usr/local/bin/node).
- n downloads and installs binary files, and nvm downloads, compiles, installs from the source.

I don't fully understand the latter part of your question, but in regards having control with node projects/apps, you can use `npm install [package_name] --save-dev` to save your npms within your 'project'.

These npm module versions (^semver) get detailed in your package.json file, for example `"gulp": "^3.8.5"` is different from `"gulp": "3.8.5"` (the later being specific to v3.8.5, and the ^3.8.5 means allowing any future version of 3, but not 4.0.0)

The differences between npm and gem is that npm installs the specified packages in the local node_modules folder (the current working directory using the `--save-dev`), so you have less worries with cross project module versions.

Important note: Running --save (instead of --save-dev) installs any missing dependencies.

I hope that helps a little :o)

Comment: If you want a cleaner way to use node_modules within a project, without messing with your local system try Docker.  Quote "Docker containers wrap up a piece of software in a complete filesystem that contains everything it needs to run: code, runtime, system tools, system libraries – anything you can install on a server. This guarantees that it will always run the same, regardless of the environment it is running in." and a [link](https://www.docker.com/)

Comment: Yes. Eventualy the end answer is all about "the way how it works" as Rod Vagg replied. And though he is not even using them most time. Also do note that `nvm` is more popular (for example Travis uses it).

Comment: I went into docker and vm tools like vagrant after this question. Tried to keep on pc own custom environments. But keeping environments aside is way more better.

Comment: @rootscript I'm editing your answer because you definitely don't understand what `--save` and `--save-dev` do - please consult the documentation. also, if you need to resort to Docker to fix some problem with `node_modules`, you're doing something very, very wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Just tried to install `nvm` and it works for switching from one version to another. In header of `nave.sh` it says "# This program contains parts of narwhal's "sea" program, as well as bits borrowed from Tim Caswell's "nvm"", so you might try both and see the tiniest difference. Also check the "popularity" of each and contributors to get some insight). There is also a `nodeenv` which uses python, but I don't any reason why use python here. So, my answer would be **no big difference**.

Comment: @RomanM.Kos Eh, don't worry about it. Just write your own ;-).

Comment: @RomanM.Kos Each developer has it's own opinion - that's why.

Comment: Those are not an answers. Its the same as "Why? Because, duh...". 

Not an answer.

Opinion comparison, and other developer preferred tools cause of specific reasons - this is the main point of the question.